# ITK filter creation and update

Tags: c++, itk

I've defined the following values for the simplex mesh and the deform filter:

```
typedef itk::SimplexMesh<float, 3> TSimplex;
typedef itk::DeformableSimplexMesh3DBalloonForceFilter<TSimplex,TSimplex> TDeform;
TSimplex::Pointer simplex = TSimplex::New();
```

I don't understand why this first code work and the second one doesn't.

```
TDeform::Pointer balloon = TDeformar::New();
balloon->SetInput(simplex);
balloon->SetKappa(0.01);
balloon->Update();
simplex = balloon->GetOutput();
simplex->DisconnectPipeline();

TDeform::Pointer balloon2 = TDeformar::New();
balloon2->SetInput(simplex);
balloon2->SetKappa(0.01);
balloon2->Update();
simplex = balloon2->GetOutput();
simplex->DisconnectPipeline();
```

This is the other one:

```
TDeform::Pointer balloon = TDeformar::New();
balloon->SetInput(simplex);
balloon->SetKappa(0.01);
balloon->Update();
simplex = balloon->GetOutput();
simplex->DisconnectPipeline();

balloon->SetInput(simplex);
balloon->SetKappa(0.01);
balloon->Update(); //Here I get an execution error on itkPoint segment violation
simplex = balloon->GetOutput();
simplex->DisconnectPipeline();
```

Comment: What is simplex before the first call to SetInput?

Comment: Just edited, simplex is a simplex mesh

Comment: A second thought, should work and I cannot reproduce the error on ITK 4.6.0.

Comment: @mainactual I'm using ITK 4.9.0, here is the code https://goo.gl/VW1cBL